# HDMI Not detected / HDMI Disconnected

Tags: linux, linux-mint, display, hdmi

I'm running Linux Mint with MATE.  My external HDMI monitors no longer work with my single HDMI port.

lspci -v

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Dell Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: hsw_uncore

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
    Memory at f6c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Dell Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    Memory at f7c34000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Dell 8 Series USB xHCI HC
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 40
    Memory at f7c20000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell 8 Series HECI
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    Memory at f7c3f000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-LM (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection I218-LM
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 41
    Memory at f7c00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Memory at f7c3c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    I/O ports at f080 [disabled] [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell 8 Series HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    Memory at f7c30000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: f7b00000-f7bfffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: f7a00000-f7afffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: f7000000-f79fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f0000000-00000000f09fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Dell 8 Series USB EHCI
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 21
    Memory at f7c3b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell 8 Series LPC Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Dell 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
    I/O ports at f0d0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f0c0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f0b0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f0a0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
    Memory at f7c3a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell 8 Series SMBus Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at f7c39000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 01)
    Subsystem: Dell SD/MMC Card Reader Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f7b01000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at f7b00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci

02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at f7a00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

inxi -Fx

```
System:
  Host: jorge-Latitude-E5440 Kernel: 4.15.0-20-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  compiler: gcc v: 7.3.0 Desktop: MATE 1.20.1 Distro: Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa 
  base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Dell product: Latitude E5440 v: 00 
  serial: <root required> 
  Mobo: Dell model: 03CHJ4 v: A00 serial: <root required> UEFI: Dell v: A21 
  date: 02/01/2018 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 40.7 Wh condition: 49.3/66.6 Wh (74%) 
  model: LGC-LGC3.0 DELL NVWGM63 status: Charging 
CPU:
  Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i5-4210U bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  arch: Haswell rev: 1 L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
  flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 19155 
  Speed: 998 MHz min/max: 800/2700 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 923 2: 899 
  3: 899 4: 904 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics vendor: Dell driver: i915 
  v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa 
  resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Haswell Mobile v: 4.5 Mesa 18.0.5 
  direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Haswell-ULT HD Audio vendor: Dell driver: snd_hda_intel 
  v: kernel bus ID: 00:03.0 
  Device-2: Intel 8 Series HD Audio vendor: Dell driver: snd_hda_intel 
  v: kernel bus ID: 00:1b.0 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.15.0-20-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Ethernet I218-LM vendor: Dell driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k 
  port: f080 bus ID: 00:19.0 
  IF: eno1 state: down mac: 34:e6:d7:10:bb:8f 
  Device-2: Intel Wireless 7260 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: f040 
  bus ID: 02:00.0 
  IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: 48:51:b7:06:b2:10 
  IF-ID-1: docker0 state: down mac: 02:42:58:2f:db:5c 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 465.76 GiB used: 41.99 GiB (9.0%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WD5000LPLX-08ZNTT0 
  size: 465.76 GiB 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 95.62 GiB used: 41.96 GiB (43.9%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda6 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 50.0 C mobo: 37.0 C sodimm: 37.0 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 0 
Info:
  Processes: 202 Uptime: 10m Memory: 7.70 GiB used: 1.07 GiB (13.9%) 
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 7.3.0 Shell: bash v: 4.4.19 
  inxi: 3.0.27
```

xrandr --verbose

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (0x46) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
    Identifier: 0x42
    Timestamp:  38912
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff004c83415400000000
        00160104901f11780a4bc59c57548c27
        17505400000001010101010101010101
        0101010101018a1b565a500027303020
        550035ae1000001a5c12565a50002730
        3020550035ae1000001a000000fe0039
        335634488031343041540a2000000000
        00004121940010000001010a202000e9
    scaling mode: Full aspect 
        supported: Full, Center, Full aspect
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
  1366x768 (0x46) 70.500MHz +HSync -VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1366 start 1414 end 1446 total 1456 skew    0 clock  48.42KHz
        v: height  768 start  773 end  778 total  807           clock  60.00Hz
  1366x768 (0x47) 47.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1366 start 1414 end 1446 total 1456 skew    0 clock  32.28KHz
        v: height  768 start  773 end  778 total  807           clock  40.00Hz
  1360x768 (0x48) 84.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1432 end 1568 total 1776 skew    0 clock  47.72KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  59.80Hz
  1360x768 (0x49) 72.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1408 end 1440 total 1520 skew    0 clock  47.37KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  790           clock  59.96Hz
  1280x720 (0x4a) 156.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1512 total 1744 skew    0 clock  89.52KHz
        v: height  720 start  721 end  724 total  746           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x4b) 120.750MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1280 start 1304 end 1320 total 1360 skew    0 clock  88.79KHz
        v: height  720 start  721 end  724 total  740           clock  59.99Hz
  1280x720 (0x4c) 74.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1344 end 1472 total 1664 skew    0 clock  44.77KHz
        v: height  720 start  723 end  728 total  748           clock  59.86Hz
  1280x720 (0x4d) 63.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  44.27KHz
        v: height  720 start  723 end  728 total  741           clock  59.74Hz
  1024x768 (0x4e) 133.475MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1024 start 1100 end 1212 total 1400 skew    0 clock  95.34KHz
        v: height  768 start  768 end  770 total  794           clock  60.04Hz
  1024x768 (0x4f) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  960x720 (0x50) 117.000MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start 1024 end 1128 total 1300 skew    0 clock  90.00KHz
        v: height  720 start  720 end  722 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  928x696 (0x51) 109.150MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   928 start  976 end 1088 total 1264 skew    0 clock  86.35KHz
        v: height  696 start  696 end  698 total  719           clock  60.05Hz
  896x672 (0x52) 102.400MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   896 start  960 end 1060 total 1224 skew    0 clock  83.66KHz
        v: height  672 start  672 end  674 total  697           clock  60.01Hz
  1024x576 (0x53) 98.500MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1024 start 1092 end 1200 total 1376 skew    0 clock  71.58KHz
        v: height  576 start  577 end  580 total  597           clock  59.95Hz
  1024x576 (0x54) 78.375MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1064 total 1104 skew    0 clock  70.99KHz
        v: height  576 start  577 end  580 total  592           clock  59.96Hz
  1024x576 (0x55) 46.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1064 end 1160 total 1296 skew    0 clock  35.88KHz
        v: height  576 start  579 end  584 total  599           clock  59.90Hz
  1024x576 (0x56) 42.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1072 end 1104 total 1184 skew    0 clock  35.47KHz
        v: height  576 start  579 end  584 total  593           clock  59.82Hz
  960x600 (0x57) 96.625MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start 1028 end 1128 total 1296 skew    0 clock  74.56KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  622           clock  59.93Hz
  960x600 (0x58) 77.000MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start  984 end 1000 total 1040 skew    0 clock  74.04KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  617           clock  60.00Hz
  960x540 (0x59) 86.500MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start 1024 end 1124 total 1288 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
        v: height  540 start  541 end  544 total  560           clock  59.96Hz
  960x540 (0x5a) 69.250MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start  984 end 1000 total 1040 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height  540 start  541 end  544 total  555           clock  59.99Hz
  960x540 (0x5b) 40.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   960 start  992 end 1088 total 1216 skew    0 clock  33.51KHz
        v: height  540 start  543 end  548 total  562           clock  59.63Hz
  960x540 (0x5c) 37.250MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   960 start 1008 end 1040 total 1120 skew    0 clock  33.26KHz
        v: height  540 start  543 end  548 total  556           clock  59.82Hz
  800x600 (0x5d) 81.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  832 end  928 total 1080 skew    0 clock  75.00KHz
        v: height  600 start  600 end  602 total  625           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x5e) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0x5f) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  840x525 (0x60) 73.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   840 start  892 end  980 total 1120 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  529 total  544           clock  60.01Hz
  840x525 (0x61) 59.500MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   840 start  864 end  880 total  920 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  529 total  540           clock  59.88Hz
  864x486 (0x62) 32.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   864 start  888 end  968 total 1072 skew    0 clock  30.32KHz
        v: height  486 start  489 end  494 total  506           clock  59.92Hz
  864x486 (0x63) 30.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   864 start  912 end  944 total 1024 skew    0 clock  29.79KHz
        v: height  486 start  489 end  494 total  500           clock  59.57Hz
  800x512 (0x64) 51.562MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  800 end  828 total  832 skew    0 clock  61.97KHz
        v: height  512 start  512 end  514 total  515           clock  60.17Hz
  700x525 (0x65) 61.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  744 end  820 total  940 skew    0 clock  64.89KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  532 total  541           clock  59.98Hz
  800x450 (0x66) 59.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  848 end  928 total 1056 skew    0 clock  55.99KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  454 total  467           clock  59.95Hz
  800x450 (0x67) 48.750MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  824 end  840 total  880 skew    0 clock  55.40KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  454 total  463           clock  59.82Hz
  640x512 (0x68) 54.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  844 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height  512 start  512 end  514 total  533           clock  60.02Hz
  720x450 (0x69) 53.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   720 start  760 end  836 total  952 skew    0 clock  55.93KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  454 total  467           clock  59.89Hz
  700x450 (0x6a) 51.750MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  740 end  812 total  924 skew    0 clock  56.01KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  456 total  467           clock  59.96Hz
  700x450 (0x6b) 43.250MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  724 end  740 total  780 skew    0 clock  55.45KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  456 total  463           clock  59.88Hz
  640x480 (0x6c) 54.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  688 end  744 total  900 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  480 start  480 end  482 total  500           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0x6d) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x405 (0x6e) 22.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  744 end  808 total  896 skew    0 clock  25.11KHz
        v: height  405 start  408 end  413 total  422           clock  59.51Hz
  720x405 (0x6f) 21.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  768 end  800 total  880 skew    0 clock  24.72KHz
        v: height  405 start  408 end  413 total  419           clock  58.99Hz
  684x384 (0x70) 42.625MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   684 start  720 end  788 total  892 skew    0 clock  47.79KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  390 total  399           clock  59.88Hz
  684x384 (0x71) 36.125MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   684 start  708 end  724 total  764 skew    0 clock  47.28KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  390 total  395           clock  59.85Hz
  680x384 (0x72) 42.375MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   680 start  716 end  784 total  888 skew    0 clock  47.72KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  390 total  399           clock  59.80Hz
  680x384 (0x73) 36.000MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   680 start  704 end  720 total  760 skew    0 clock  47.37KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  390 total  395           clock  59.96Hz
  640x400 (0x74) 41.750MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  676 end  740 total  840 skew    0 clock  49.70KHz
        v: height  400 start  401 end  404 total  415           clock  59.88Hz
  640x400 (0x75) 35.500MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  664 end  680 total  720 skew    0 clock  49.31KHz
        v: height  400 start  401 end  404 total  411           clock  59.98Hz
  576x432 (0x76) 40.810MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   576 start  608 end  668 total  760 skew    0 clock  53.70KHz
        v: height  432 start  432 end  434 total  447           clock  60.06Hz
  640x360 (0x77) 37.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  672 end  736 total  832 skew    0 clock  44.77KHz
        v: height  360 start  361 end  364 total  374           clock  59.86Hz
  640x360 (0x78) 31.875MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  664 end  680 total  720 skew    0 clock  44.27KHz
        v: height  360 start  361 end  364 total  370           clock  59.83Hz
  640x360 (0x79) 18.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  800 skew    0 clock  22.50KHz
        v: height  360 start  363 end  368 total  376           clock  59.84Hz
  640x360 (0x7a) 17.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  688 end  720 total  800 skew    0 clock  22.19KHz
        v: height  360 start  363 end  368 total  374           clock  59.32Hz
  512x384 (0x7b) 32.500MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   512 start  524 end  592 total  672 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  388 total  403           clock  60.00Hz
  512x288 (0x7c) 23.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   512 start  532 end  580 total  648 skew    0 clock  35.88KHz
        v: height  288 start  289 end  292 total  299           clock  60.00Hz
  512x288 (0x7d) 21.000MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   512 start  536 end  552 total  592 skew    0 clock  35.47KHz
        v: height  288 start  289 end  292 total  296           clock  59.92Hz
  480x270 (0x7e) 20.375MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   480 start  496 end  544 total  608 skew    0 clock  33.51KHz
        v: height  270 start  271 end  274 total  281           clock  59.63Hz
  480x270 (0x7f) 18.625MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   480 start  504 end  520 total  560 skew    0 clock  33.26KHz
        v: height  270 start  271 end  274 total  278           clock  59.82Hz
  400x300 (0x80) 20.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   400 start  420 end  484 total  528 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  300 start  300 end  302 total  314           clock  60.32Hz
  400x300 (0x81) 18.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   400 start  412 end  448 total  512 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  300 start  300 end  301 total  312           clock  56.34Hz
  432x243 (0x82) 16.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   432 start  444 end  484 total  536 skew    0 clock  30.32KHz
        v: height  243 start  244 end  247 total  253           clock  59.92Hz
  432x243 (0x83) 15.250MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   432 start  456 end  472 total  512 skew    0 clock  29.79KHz
        v: height  243 start  244 end  247 total  250           clock  59.57Hz
  320x240 (0x84) 12.587MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  328 end  376 total  400 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  240 start  245 end  246 total  262           clock  60.05Hz
  360x202 (0x85) 11.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   360 start  372 end  404 total  448 skew    0 clock  25.11KHz
        v: height  202 start  204 end  206 total  211           clock  59.51Hz
  360x202 (0x86) 10.875MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   360 start  384 end  400 total  440 skew    0 clock  24.72KHz
        v: height  202 start  204 end  206 total  209           clock  59.13Hz
  320x180 (0x87)  9.000MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  332 end  360 total  400 skew    0 clock  22.50KHz
        v: height  180 start  181 end  184 total  188           clock  59.84Hz
  320x180 (0x88)  8.875MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  344 end  360 total  400 skew    0 clock  22.19KHz
        v: height  180 start  181 end  184 total  187           clock  59.32Hz
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x43
    Timestamp:  38912
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:     HDMI-1
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x44
    Timestamp:  38912
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:     DP-1
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
```

cat /etc/linuxmint/info

```
RELEASE=19.1
CODENAME=tessa
EDITION="Cinnamon"
DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa"
DESKTOP=Gnome
TOOLKIT=GTK
NEW_FEATURES_URL=https://www.linuxmint.com/rel_tessa_cinnamon_whatsnew.php
RELEASE_NOTES_URL=https://www.linuxmint.com/rel_tessa_cinnamon.php
USER_GUIDE_URL=https://www.linuxmint.com/documentation.php
GRUB_TITLE=Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled the drivers, rebooted, and now the two LG monitors work again.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade &&  sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```